# Use Cell references within SUM function (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am trying to create a function in one sheet, that sums up information on another sheet and as I will be running this multiple times with different datasets, I need this to be flexible. I am trying to use Cell references for this, like the following: `Range("AP3") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Results").Range(Cells(3, AEPC), Cells(LR, AEPC)))` but it fails.

AEPc is the column number and LR is the last row. I can provide the full script if required.

The annoying thing is - it does recognise the sheet and when i try and select the rows using that last line of code, it works. For some reason, it does not like it when I put that into a Sum function.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
    Sub Functions()

Dim desiredShetName As Worksheet
Dim NewName As Worksheet



ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Counts_Tables_Macro").Activate

Set desiredSheetName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")



    'Finding the AEP box in Counts Tab to run calculations
    'AEPNC = WorksheetFunction.Match(AEP, Worksheets(NewName).Rows(16), 0)
    
    'Finding the corresponding AEP box in Results Tab
    AEPC = WorksheetFunction.Match("5YR", Worksheets("Results").Rows(2), 0)
    
    'Finding the residential property Column in Results Tab
    PropNumC = WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("DATA IN").Range("D2"), Worksheets("Results").Rows(2), 0)
    
    'Finding the 'Class' column in Results Tab ** Requires change if column name changes **
    ClassC = WorksheetFunction.Match("Class", Worksheets("Results").Rows(2), 0)
    
    'Getting last row in Results Tab
    With Sheets("Results")
        LR = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
    End With
    
'this is all testing
Range("AP1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("AA10:AA12"))

Range("AP2") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Results").Range("DU3:DU17079"))

Set Crange = Range(Cells(3, AEPC), Cells(LR, AEPC))
'Range(Cells(3, AEPC), Cells(LR, AEPC)).Select

'Sheets("Results").Select
'Sheets("Results").Range(Cells(3, AEPC), Cells(LR, AEPC)).Select


Range("AP3") = 1
Range("AP3") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Results").Range(Cells(3, AEPC), Cells(LR, AEPC)))






'Range("AP2") = SumV
'Range("AP2") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(WorkSheets("CBC_PIX_OSMM_MIT6-with 10%C (3)).Range("DU3:DU1700"))



'Range("C18").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF('" & desiredSheetName & "' !R[3]C[ClassC]:R[LR]C[ClassC], '" & NewName & "' !R[17]C[2], '" & NewName & "'!R[3]C[AEPC]:R[LR]C[AEPC])"


End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Its Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Not an answer but you've dimmed `desiredShetName` and used `desiredSheetName`.  Having [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/option-explicit-statement) at the top of the module would have highlighted this.

Comment: `Worksheets("Results").Range(Cells(3, AEPC), Cells(LR, AEPC))`.  `Range` refers to the Results sheet, but `Cells` refers to the activesheet as you haven't fully qualified the cell.  If `Range` and `Cells` are on different sheets an error will occur.

Comment: TRy `Range("AP3") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Results").Range(Worksheets("Results").Cells(3, AEPC), Worksheets("Results").Cells(LR, AEPC)))`

Comment: Thank you ExcelEverything. That worked! Legend!!

Answer (score 0):

You're not declaring where your cells within the formula are.

I haven't looked at all your code as there's a lot of chaff in there - comments and irrelevant lines of code.

This procedure hopefully points out the mistake:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim LR As Long
    LR = 10
    
    Dim AEPC As Long
    AEPC = 5
    
    Dim ResultSheet As Worksheet
    Set ResultSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA IN")
    
    'Qualify all range and cell references.
    'You should also use the workbook - ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results").Range(.....
    Dim SumResult As Long
    SumResult = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ResultSheet.Range(ResultSheet.Cells(3, AEPC), ResultSheet.Cells(LR, AEPC)))

End Sub
```

by the looks of it your Sum line should read:

```
Worksheets("Results").Range("AP3") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Results").Range(Worksheets("Results").Cells(3, AEPC), Worksheets("Results").Cells(LR, AEPC)))
```